# Reduce the number of lines of code in python

Tags: python

how can I write this function in 2 lines?

```
def avg_prod(it1, it2):
    l = list(zip(it1, it2))
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        result = (l[i][0]*l[i][1])/(i+1)
        total += result
    return total/len(l)
```

Comment: `return sum[(l[i][0]*l[i][1])/(i+1) for i in range(len(l))]/len(l)`

Comment: I think not.   The problem is dividing by len(n), rather than successive values of i + 1

Comment: @MarkLavin so it seems you still have stuff to learn ;) see my answer ;)

Comment: @azro, the stuff I need to learn is boundless :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use indices, but unpack the values in the for loop

```
def avg_prod(it1, it2):
    total = 0
    for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(zip(it1, it2)):
        total += (v1*v2) / (i+1)
    return total / min(len(it1), len(it2))
```

Then use `sum` method

```
def avg_prod(it1, it2):
    return sum((v1*v2) / (i+1) for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(zip(it1, it2))) / min(len(it1), len(it2))
```

---

You can change `min(len(it1), len(it2))` by `len(it1)` it both lists are always of the same length